# Eclipse: Function 'next' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I saw quite a lot of similar questions in forums, but none of them
helped me.

EClipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0) in

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I created a makefile project with  existing code, 
it builds fine, but code indexer could not find some of newer
std functions, e.g. iterator::next() or vector::shrink_to_fit();

popular answeres were 
-"In your project explorer window, right click on your project -> Index -> Rebuild"

-"Project > Properties > Settings > Binary Parsers > "GNU Elf Parser""

-"add under Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings then on the Tool Settings tab GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous the -std=c++11 flag, "

include paths look fine, it can find other standart c++ functions.

Below is a portion from the code

```
void TECTrig::ReadECTriggerPeak(){
  has_TrigPeak = true;

  TEC_Peak cur_peak;
  cur_peak.inst = fit_data->range(26, 26);
  cur_peak.view = fit_data->range(25, 24);

  fpeak_coord_hls(8, 0) = fit_data->range(23, 15);
  cur_peak.coord = fpeak_coord_hls.to_double();
  cur_peak.energy = fit_data->range(14, 2);

  fit_data = std::next(fit_data, 1);   // Go to the next word
  // This should be data continuation word, if not then data format is not correct
  if( fit_data->range(31, 31) ) {printf("Wrong Data Format in %s Exiting", __func__); exit(0); }

  cur_peak.time = fit_data->range(10, 0);

  fv_ECAllPeaks.push_back(cur_peak);

  fv_ind_ECPeak[cur_peak.inst][cur_peak.view].push_back(fv_ECAllPeaks.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Maybe before You find bug in compiler, put Your code?

Comment: Thank @JacekCz for the replay, I just edited my question, adding a small
portion of the code, 

The code, that it doesn't understand is
fit_data = std::next(fit_data, 1);